# Copy web-builder created website to new hosting

Tags: file-upload, mapping, hosting

I have a website created in a web-building online app (link to the app: http://www.webnode.com). The app doesn't allow me to actually view the folder structure of my web, it's something more like creating a blog using blogspot by google or similar web apps.

The problem is that I want to quit using that web builder and map the whole website to my private hosting. In order to do it I need to get somehow my web created in this app into the folder structure (or any other uploadable structure).

I'll be very grateful for any kind of advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be easily done using **winhttrack** application, which downloads entire website to your computer.